# making sublist from sublist based on index position python

Tags: python

I have a list

```
mainlist=[[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'],[4,5,6,7]]
```

want to make sublist based on index position in sublist. The output is

```
finallist=[[1,'a',4],[2,'b',5],[3,'c',6],[4,'d',7]]
```

Thanks

Comment: complete duplicate (`zip(...)`) . Use search bar on SO

Comment: `print(list(map(list, zip(*mainlist))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip` with unpacking:

```
finallist = list(map(list, zip(*mainlist)))
```

Comment: Austin: Thanks...